# How can i launch an iOS app which installed already using appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios

In order to test the duplication in registering,I need to close and relaunch the iOS application.Can any one provide the best and simple scripts to close an application and relaunch the same in iOS using Appium and JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

*You can achieve the following way :*

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class SampleTest {
    AppiumDriver<?> appiumDriver;
    final String URL_STRING = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";
    URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);

    public SampleTest() throws MalformedURLException {
    }

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
         File appDir = new File("path to ipa file");
    File app = new File(appDir, "app.ipa");
    DesiredCapabilities iOSCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    iOSCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, "iOS");
    iOSCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
    iOSCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone6s");
    iOSCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11.2.1");
    iOSCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "udid");
    iOSCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
    appiumDriver = new IOSDriver(url, iOSCapabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //perform some test
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        // following command will close and restart the app
        appiumDriver.resetApp();
    }
}
```

*You may want to check [this](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/commands/device/app/reset-app/) for more details.*

Answer (score 0):

use the driver `driver.resetApp()`, like this

```
try{
      LOG.debug("reset app");
      driver.resetApp();
    } catch (WebDriverException e){
      LOG.error("ERROR on reset app, e: ",e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Appium allows you to start any pre-installed app on the device, so you can use `closeApp` first and then `launchApp` with your app bundle id:

```java
            // closing app
            driver.closeApp();
            // launch app again
            HashMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
            args.put("bundleId", APP_BUNDLE_ID);
            driver.executeScript("mobile: launchApp", args);
```